# Can you volunteer on the B1/B2 visa?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, australian-citizens

I'm an Australian Citizen who has been invited to volunteer in the States for 3 1/2 months with a letter of invitation. I will not be getting paid, all food and accommodation are covered by them and anything else is from me.
Can I use the B1/B2 visa?

Comment: According to the [US Fish and Wildlife Service](https://www.fws.gov/volunteers/internantionalVolunteers.html), only if it's through a recognized religious or charitable non-profit organization.

Comment: @pnuts people entering on VWP are under the same restrictions as B1/B2 holders. Close-voting.

Comment: @ptityeti I've edited the question

Comment: @ptityeti Splitting answers across multiple questions can't be good for the site. It makes it harder to find information and harder to keep that information up to date.